# Filter mysql data for chart visualisation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, charts

On my portal I have a chart (devexpress) which uses an API to load JSON records.

In my example I have a sensor which inserts a new record into the database every 60 seconds with following fields: `id`, `serialnumber`, `tag_id`, `timestamp`, `value`. So on any one day I have about 1440 datapoints in the database.

On the chart I have a datepicker, which I can choose a specific time range. Now when I choose, "last month", my AJAX call will send the 2 timestamps (now and now - 1 month) to the API.

So I will get 30 x 1440 records for my chart. This is too many. Now I need a solution, that when I chose a 7 day period, I get one record for each hour or when I chose last month I get just one record every day as an average of all the records for the day.

My SQL query on the API is:

```
SELECT * FROM `records` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN "' . $posts['from'] . '" AND "' . $posts['to'] . '"'
```

Comment: Restructured a large portion of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add GROUP BY to your sql. In following example you will find exact solution for your needs.

[Grouping timestamps in MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185973/grouping-timestamps-in-mysql-with-php)